# Can you set custom UISlider values?

Tags: ios, uislider

Instead of a range when using UISlider, is it possible to set custom values such as `A, B, C...` or `0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 2, 3, 4....`

Or do I need to create my own mapping data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UISlider stores its value as `float`.
Thus you'll either need an additional **mapping data structure** or an analogous **mapping algorithm**.

If your custom UISlider is meant to be used over and over again in your app you might consider subclassing UISlider and making the mapping structure/algorithm a private member of it for convenience.